# DAX Filter Function to not filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

Below is the code I am using to try and prevent a power BI visual (which is a card) from filtering when any of the filters are selected except for the 'Site' filter. I have used the EXCEPT function but when other filters are selected the Card visual still filters when it shouldn't. Any help be much appreciated. Thanks.

[image: DAX Code]

Comment: Which of the steps yield an erroneous value?

Comment: You see there is no error being given. When I filter other visuals this one just decides to filter too which is that we don't want.

Comment: Sorry - What I mean is: which of the returned variables are not calculated correctly in terms of the unwanted filtering?